# View that extends Gallery + Adapter: How to inform view of changes?

Tags: android, gallery, adapter

I have a view that extends Gallery (In order to create a cover flow).
Now I need the title of the currently selected (speak: The one that's shown in the front) to be displayed at the top.

So far, that's no problem since I can just use:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
    if(mSpinnerAdapter.getItem(position)!=null) {
        mSelectedTextView.setText((CharSequence) ((MyDataItem)mSpinnerAdapter.getItem(arg2)).getName());
    } 
}
```

The data comes from a web service and is therefore slow, so as long as the data is not loaded, I am displaying a progress bar. I am doing this by telling the adapter to deliver a progress bar in "getView(..)"¨and a "1" in "getCount()" as long as the data structure is not fully loaded (Hence the if(mSpinnerAdapter.getItem(position)!=null) in the code above).

Now the problem is this: When the data from the web is loaded, I call onDatasetChanged() on the adapter and the gallery view is being updated (which works), but without onItemSelected() being called. The consequence of this is that the title is not set for the first item.

How can I solve this? Or is my technique to display the progress bar wrong alltogether?

Thank you!